# Unable to connect to SQL Server using EF Core when running app in Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, entity-framework-core

I am having a problem connecting to an SQL Server instance running on my local machine. I am using EF Core and I am running my app in Docker. When I try to obtain data from the database I get the following exception:

[image]

Here is my connection string configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
"Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Cars;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"));
```

and here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Cars.Api/Cars.Api.csproj", "Cars.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Cars.Api/Cars.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Cars.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Cars.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Cars.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Cars.Api.dll"]
```

It should also be noted that everything works perfectly fine when I run the project as a console application.

If you need any additional information or clarification, please feel free to ask me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `.` is a synonym for `localhost`. Docker containers are like little Linux VMs so each one considers `localhost` to be referencing itself. If the SQL Server Express instance is running on the Docker host have you tried using `Server=host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS;` in your connection string?

Comment: Aside... `Trusted_Connection=True;` is unlikely to work from a Docker container - unless you've setup Kerberos authentication in the container. You may need to use SQL Login credentials with `User ID=...;Password=...;` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am going to try your suggestions out and let you know if any of them turns out to be successful.